# HTML5 Storage / JQuery Not saving Data

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I am trying to get some html5 localstorage working but with no luck.

It's not saving and when I click the "Click to Save" link I don't get the alert on the function.

I'm I forgetting something here?

Here's the full code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

loaddata(); //Load the saved data

function loaddata() {
    $('#mydiv').val(localStorage.mydata);

}


function savedata() {
    localStorage.mydata = $('#mydiv').val();
    alert('Data Saved!'); //This is not showing up
} 


});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" onclick="savedata();">Click to Save</a>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="mydiv">0</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your functions shouldn't be in the $(document).ready section. They should be outside that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access `savedata` from the onclick handler of your link, because it's wrapped in the `document.ready` call.

Either move `savedata` out of the `document.ready` or use jQuery to attach the click handler directly to the element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    loaddata(); //Load the saved data

    function loaddata() {
        $('#mydiv').html(localStorage.mydata);

    }
});

function savedata() {
    localStorage.mydata = $('#mydiv').html();
    alert('Data Saved!'); //This is not showing up
}
```

Or the other way

```
<a href="#" id="savebtn">Click to Save</a>

$("#savebtn").click(function() {
    localStorage.mydata = $('#mydiv').val();
    alert('Data Saved!'); //This is not showing up
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rnhD/) that fixes your errors, including trying to use `.val()` on a `td` element. It also changes the data to different values you can see if it is working or not.

Comment: OK, I've moved the savedata() function out and it now alerts but when I refresh it's not loading any new data :o/  Any ideas?

Comment: @Satch3000, what exactly are you saving as new data? On load you load the value of `localStorage.mydata` into `myDiv` and then you save `myDiv` into `localStorage.mydata`. At no point does the value change, you're just sending the same data back and forth.

Comment: @Satch3000, one more thing. You've assigned the `id` to a `td` which means you can't use `.val()`. Use `.html()` instead.

Comment: The td has a a starting value text of 0 but the value changes using jquery and the value between <td> and </td> is what I want to save and then extract. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Satch3000, look at the jsFiddle I posted. It will show you what you have to do.

Comment: I've checked the jsFiddle and it would be perfect if instead of the date it saved the data / text at mydiv.

Comment: @Satch3000, You can make it save whatever you want. Date was just the easiest example to show that it was in fact saving and updating properly. If you want it to save the data from mydiv, replace the date with `$("#mydiv").html()`.